# Show title for every page ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, page-title

I have a layout page, which has a title, and rest of the pages has there own title i want to show the title in the browser for each page user visit. Currently it display the title of the layout page.

**layout page**

```
<title>page layout tile</title>
```

**every child page**

Child Page

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Download Me</title>
</head>
```

the browser show the title of layout page for every page.

**My Effort**

No description has been provided in the title of layout page, then browser by default show the url of page as title

layout page

```
<title></title>
```

Answer (score 5):

In your Layout page set title as

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
```

and in view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My title";
}
```

or else you can pass the `ViewBag.Title` from the controller itself.

Answer (score 0):

layout page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
```

every child page

Child Page

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Download Me";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in layout page

`<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>`

and in every child page use

`@{  ViewBag.Title = "Download-page"; }`

Comment: This will print the title in the View put @ViewBag.Title inside <title> tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this one;

```
  @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Your title";
   }
```

add:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mention before by the others you need to set in your layout file the following:

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
```

Andthen you can set it by your view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My view title"
}
```

or by your controller:

```
ViewBag.Title = "My controller title"
```

because you want to reuse your views mostly you might want to do this in your controller.

you can read more about that over at this website. You can use the ViewBag for a lot of data to be transferred to views.
http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/viewbag-in-asp.net-mvc